# Python Selenium: Set Firefox preferences failed

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

I'm trying to automate a file download in a web page using selenium.
We can consider for example that I will try to automate the download of geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

My python code is the following:

That's the code that I used:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", path)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", path)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip, application/tar+gzip, application/x-gtar, application/x-compressed")
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.update_preferences()
browser =  webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get('https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases')

sleep(5)
try:
    field = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='release-downloads']//li/a/strong[contains(text(),'geckodriver-v0.11.1-linux64.tar.gz')]")
    if(field != None):
    field.click()
    find = True
except Exception,e: 
    print str(e)
```

My problem is that if I try this code I got the popup download of firefox:

[image]

I thought that maybe I set bad value of the preference browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk, so I tried to download the zip file but I got the same problem. Then I took look on about:config but unfortunately I found that parameters are set to default values. For example I found the value of browser.download.folderList is 1 but not 2:

[image]

also browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk is null value, and browser.download.dir doesn't exist.

**Edit: Download without setting preferences**

Then I try without setting preferences with this code:

```
browser =  webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases')

sleep(5)
try:
    field = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='release-downloads']//li/a/strong[contains(text(),'geckodriver-v0.11.1-linux64.tar.gz')]")
    if(field != None):
    field.click()
    find = True
except Exception,e: 
    print str(e)
    pass
```

But I get the same problem like that setting preferences part that I deleted hasn't any influence.
But taking in consideration that if I open Firefox manually  and click manually in the download link I can download the file directly with the confirm popup of firefox without any problem.

Is there  mistakes in my code? or what's the problem?

Development environment: Python2.7, selenium3.0.1, Firefox 49.

Comment: I believe I solved this issue here [Python Selenium Download Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644381/python-set-firefox-preferences-for-selenium-download-location/41683377#41683377)
.

Answer (score 0):

You should use semicolon to separate mime types:

profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip;application/tar+gzip;application/x-gtar;application/x-compressed")