# Python Set Firefox Preferences for Selenium--Download Location

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I use Selenium Marrionette and GeckoDriver to pull web data. I use the following to set my Firefox profile preferences:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 1)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "H:\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir","H:\Downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder","H:\Downloads")

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile = fp)
```

From what I understand after reading [Unable to set firefox profile preferences](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/236) and [FirefoxProfile passed to FirefoxDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2572), it seems that nothing is being done when using `firefox_profile` now. So I need to implement the new updates to `firefox_capabilities`, but I'm not sure how to exactly do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I believe I finally figured this mess out. Instead of using the code above, I used the following code which I point to my Firefox profile folder(if you need to update your default profile settings do that in Firefox before running this code):

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
fp = (r'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\oqmqnsih.default')
opts = Options()
opts.profile = fp
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities,firefox_binary=binary, firefox_options = opts)
```

I ran this code along with my web-scraping code and once I clicked the "Export CSV" link, it automatically downloaded as opposed to the Download Manager window popping up. Feel free to add any feedback.

Comment: wish I'd found this months ago!

Answer (score 3):

The initial code is partialy correct. You must set browser.download.folderList value as 2 :

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) # 0 means to download to the desktop, 1 means to download to the default "Downloads" directory, 2 means to use the directory 
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "H:\Downloads") 

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities,firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile = fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution for my python script (on raspi 3):

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities={'browserName': 'firefox' }, firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?