# Click on a file to download Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium (python) and Firefox portable browser.

My goal is to download a lot of files using selenium (namely through Selenium).
When you click on the link, the file should start downloading, but this window opens.

[image]

Tell me, are there any selenium settings to avoid opening such a window?

Comment: You can do that using firefox profile. Below links might be  helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644381/python-set-firefox-preferences-for-selenium-download-location 
 https://gist.github.com/acdcjunior/123423d40717efa667a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try to set preference `neverAsk.saveToDisk`*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def example():
    opt = Options()
    opt.headless = False  # Or True

    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
                      "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\folder_name\\Downloads")

    firefox_browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, options=opt)
```

*file type https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html*